# how to disable right click, f12(debug) and ctrl+s in asp.net application using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

how to disable right click, f12(debug) and ctrl+s in asp.net application using javascript or jquery.. 
Have to black ctrl+s --> Do not allow to save the page 
Have to black f12 and right click--> Do not allow to inspect/debug/view source of the page

Comment: I hope this is not for security reason than you are looking for preventing that behaviour

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Just wondering, which bank website it is?... ;)

Comment: @ A. Wolff just for security purpose.. is there any possibility to block ctrl+s?

Comment: @naveenkumar That will not help improve your "security" ***at all***.

Comment: @naveenkumar "for security purpose" But that's for sure a no go... Sensible datas are set and get server side, it must not be provided client side. You have then to redesign all your logic/system

Comment: The requirements for the project you assigned were written by people who have no clue how the internet works. yes you can try to prevent them, but it is impossible to block them. I can put up a proxy and never even have to touch my browser to get the data that you are trying to prevent from being viewed. Fiddler FTW!

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, your second comment is great! Dear naveenkumar please tell us, which bank are you working for? I won't put my money there but I can always wander around :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Do not allow to save the page" - This is impossible, as this would require not delivering the page to the user in the first place.

"Do not allow to inspect/debug/view source of the page" - This is also impossible. In Chrome you can prepend `view-source:` to the URL, and you can get to developer tools with Menu -> Tools -> Developer Tools. In any case, the browser *has* to have access to the source code to actually display the page.

What you are trying to do is impossible. There is also absolutely no reason to. (It's also highly annoying to legitimate users who actually want to right click!) If you're trying to do this for "security," this is most definitely not your biggest problem. If there's any insecure information delivered to client side, you have to redesign your entire system **immediately**.

Comment: oops..I have disabled right click.. there is no script for block ctrl+s too?

Comment: @naveenkumar You could, but it would not prevent saving the page anyway. Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @naveenkumar "I have disabled right click." That can still be re-enabled. So ya, why are you looking for that kind of behaviour?

Comment: yes to prevent the page saving.. for example in a page we are listing customers last 5 transaction using the knockout.js. in source it wont display.. it thay save the page means it will stored as html data.. so that I want to prevent this...

Comment: @naveenkumar I continue to tell you that **it is impossible** to prevent the user from saving the page.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about it! I can write my own web browser which doesn't have `right click`, `F12` and `CTRL+S` and I can still see the HTML and Javascript source. I can even do this with `telnet`.
If your manager gave you such requirements I would tell him to go back to primary school.
I know you can't tell him this. But really:
**You can't rely on the fact that some user agents will respect your tricks.**
This won't improve security - this will give you nothing.

Just some background information:
Some time ago I've written a script for Selenium WebDriver to control Firefox. I was able to grab any data, read all the scripts and moreover **inject my own JS to any website.**
You should listen to the comments and answers and **provide security on the server side** because everything your server sends as a response can be read, saved and processed one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

There are some legitimate reasons for this functionality. We are doing web-based testing in a school district and we have to provide a reasonable assurance that students will not be able to find the source file of a test and download it or email it to themselves during the test. For that reason we have to disable right click and do everything we can to ensure that F12 and Ctrl U does not work. School districts with minimal budgets have no choice but to rely on these tricks to help get more done with less.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.layers) {
//Capture the MouseDown event.
                    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);

                    //Disable the OnMouseDown event handler.
                    document.onmousedown = function () {
                        return false;
                    };
                }
                else {
                    //Disable the OnMouseUp event handler.
                    document.onmouseup = function (e) {
                        if (e != null && e.type == "mouseup") {
                            //Check the Mouse Button which is clicked.
                            if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) {
                                //If the Button is middle or right then disable.
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }

                //Disable the Context Menu event.
                document.oncontextmenu = function () {
                    return false;
                };
                document.onkeydown = ShowKeyCode;
                function ShowKeyCode(evt) {
                    if (evt.keyCode == '123')
                        return false;
                     //For F12 Button 
                }
</script>
```